# Internet<->Server<->Router<->Computers Setup

Tags: router, internet

Another question related to network setup.
Idea is to setup network as following:
Internet<->Server 2k3<->DLink 655 Router<->computers, etc

But the main point is to keep direct internet connection on server and provide internet access to all computers connected to router.

Question is how to?

Thank you

P.S. Server has two Ethernet ports

Comment: So why not use the firewall that's built into the DLink instead of having to harden the Windows 2003 server?  Are you looking to be able to audit the traffic that's hitting the internet?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your model of router specifically, but many support a DMZ function where you can assign one of your external IP addresses directly through to one of the ports on the router separate from the NAT functions that would provide service to your workstations.  This is usually easier to configure than setting up your server to be directly connected AND have to act as a gateway for your internal network (in which case you might as well not even have the router involved since your server would be serving that purpose anyway).